# 90's cartoon movie: love story between a girl and a prince who both turn into cranes

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

It's a 90's movie I think.

It is a love story involving a girl who turns into a crane. I think a jewel is involved.

At the end of the movie, both her and her prince are cranes and they fly away.

Pretty sure it's a grandma telling a story to her grandchild and there's a storm.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to find ways to improve your question.

Answer (score 6):

[*The Admiral and the Princess*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1194096/) (1990).

From wiki [search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Entertainment/2007_November_18#The_Blood_Crystal_.28The_Admiral_.26_The_Princess.29_animated_short):

> It started with the **grandmother telling her grandson** about an admiral [who] was in love with a princess. ... It starts off in the middle of a **storm**, just like the storm that the grandma and grandson are waiting to end

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/BittersweetEnding/AnimatedFilms) (first entry):

> In *The Admiral And The Princess* (aka *The Blood Crystal*), the Big Bad Court Mage has been defeated after his **amulet** (the Blood Crystal) has been shattered (killing him). But unfortunately, **the titular admiral forever remains a heron**, and the Big Bad's amulet was the only thing that could turn him back human. The admiral realizes this, knowing he and the titular princess can never be together now, and flies away. But not wanting to be without him, **the princess begged her father the king and her nanny to turn her into an egret**, knowing she won't ever become human again, and possibly not see them or her friends and subjects again. **The movie ends with the two birds flying together** (and helping lost ships) as the credits roll.